# How to ask the best food in a restaurant?

Tags: word-choice

Lets say you are in a restaurant with your friend. How do you ask to your friend "What is the best food in this restaurant?" I mean is there a better way to ask the "best food"? or is there a better word instead of "best food"?

Comment: You might say "What do you recommend?", or "Are there any specialties?".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are several ways to ask a question like this, each with slightly different nuances of meaning. Some would be:

> - What do the do well here?
> - What do they do best here?
> - What do you like most here?
> - What is your favorite here?
> - Do they have a particular specialty here?
> - Are there dishes that they do particularly well here?
> - What would you recommend here?
> - What kind of food would you recommend here?
> - What particular dish would you recommend here?

One problem is that "best food" can mean "most tasty" or "most nutritious" or "most healthy". Another is that what is "best" in any of those senses is a matter of opinion. Yet another is whether the asker is asking for a specific dish or a a type of dish: that is, is the asker looking for an answer such as"They do steaks very well here" or "I suggest that you get the prime rib"?

Comment: It also depends on who you're talking to. If OP was asking a person who works at the restaurant, such as a waiter, it's more normal to say "what would you recommend?" Whereas talking to a friend is so casual that OP has a lot of options. Even the original suggestion of "best food" is fine.

Answer (score 1):

> Oi what's the most popular dish here?
> What do you recommend we get?
> So what's good here mate?